# Use of Interactive API documentation with OpenAPI GitLab

Tags: spring, gitlab, swagger, documentation, openapi

I would like to use the Interactive API documentation (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/openapi/openapi_interactive.html). I generated a file openapi.json as artifact from pipeline. If  I download the file and upload in the folder of the repo deocumentation it is clearly visisble as Swagger UI. How can I make automatic the passage from artifact to repository?
From the documentation is not so clear how to use Interactive API documentation.
Thanks